# Importing a repository from local server via Gitlab CE

Tags: gitlab, repository

I m trying to import repository from my local server to self hosted gitlab CE. But I m getting the following error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoimB.png)

I d be appreciated for any suggestion

I already enabled the "Allow requests to the local network from webhooks and integrations" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdh2g.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.